# Save incoming file into folder and if it doesn't exist, create it

Tags: java

I'm writing my first Java program and I'm trying to implement saving/creating directory.

I'm good on the saving file part, not so on creating a new directory.

This is my attempt on saving file into directory and creating it, if it does not exists

```java
String fileName = in.readUTF();
String directoryName = "/outfiles/";

int length = in.readInt();
System.out.println("Length: " + length);

if (length > 0)
{
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    if (! directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdir();
    }
    
    // read the message
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[length];
    in.readFully(fileContent, 0, fileContent.length);

    File file_save = new File(directory, fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_save);
    fos.write(fileContent);

    // Close file output
    fos.close();
}
```

This is working code that saves file in location that .jar file itself is located

```java
String fileName = in.readUTF();
System.out.println("File: " + fileName);

int length = in.readInt();
System.out.println("Length: " + length);

if (length > 0)
{
    // read the message
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[length];
    in.readFully(fileContent, 0, fileContent.length);

    // Write bytes to file
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    fos.write(fileContent);

    // Close file output
    fos.close();
}
```

How can I make my code work?

Comment: What happens when you run it?

Comment: When i press run, and save a picture I can see the console logs that i have in function but i don't see file or folder created. I've searched for folder name in project folder and got no result.

Comment: Are you running the app as a user that has permission to create things in the "/" directory?  If not, the `directory.mkdir()` call will fail and return `false`.  If you were using `java.nio.file.Files` methods for this (instead of the legacy `File` class), you would get exceptions that tell you more about what is happening.

Comment: Note: on a typical Linux / UNIX system, a normal user cannot create directories or files in "/".  You need to be "root" to do it.

Comment: I would use `if (directory.exists() || directory.mkdirs()) { // write here // }` - this way, you're guaranteed to know the directory exists (or not)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okat, thanks to the comments I've figured it out.

```
String fileName = in.readUTF();
String directoryName = Path.of("").toAbsolutePath().toString() + "\\server-recived";

System.out.println("File: " + fileName);

// Get length of incoming file
int length = in.readInt();
System.out.println("Length: " + length);

// Get contents of file
if (length > 0)
{
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    if (! directory.exists()){
        directory.mkdir();
    }
    // read the message
    byte[] fileContent = new byte[length];
    in.readFully(fileContent, 0, fileContent.length);

    // Write bytes to file
    File file_save = new File(directory, fileName);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file_save);
    fos.write(fileContent);

    // Close file output
    fos.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
String directoryName = "outfiles"; // remove the leading slash
```